# Variable productimage not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've set up a product with multiple variations. I want to have a single image (for all variations) and a imagegallery. I've set a featured image and added a image to the productgallery. I've also set an image under "Variations".

I've read that this problem could be caused by not having a secure connection (SSL Certificate), so I installed Let's Encrypt.

The images don't show up, but I can see the URL in the code. What is going wrong?

https://do-it-creatief.nl/product/scheepjeswol-stonewashed/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set opacity from 0 to 1 in woocommerce.css

.product.has-default-attributes.has-children>.images{opacity:1}

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Why would the default css hide that image?

Comment: even i don't understand this issue with woocommerce.css. As it works perfectly with some themes